# Event is not catched in my test with stubbed function

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, sinon, chai

I'm running a problem I don't get. The event I emit is not catched in my test.
Here is the following code (`event.js`):

```
var util = require('util'),
    proc = require('child_process'),
    EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;

var Event = function() {
    var _self = this;
    proc.exec('ls -l', function(error, stdout, stderr) {
        _self.emit('test');
        console.log('emitted');
    });
};
util.inherits(Event, EventEmitter);

module.exports = Event;
```

And the according test:

```
var proc = require('child_process'),
    sinon = require('sinon'),
    chai = require('chai'),
    expect = chai.expect,
    Event = require('./event'),
    myEvent, exec;

var execStub = function() {
    var _self = this;
    return sinon.stub(proc, 'exec', function(cmd, callback) {
        _self.cmd = cmd;
        console.log(cmd);
        callback();
    });
};

describe('Event', function() {
    beforeEach(function(){
        exec = execStub();
    });

    afterEach(function(){
        exec.restore();
    });

    it('Event should be fired', function(done) {
        myEvent = new Event();
        myEvent.on('test', function() {
            expect(exec.cmd).to.equal('ls -l');
            done();
        });
    });
});
```

For now, here is what I see:

- the event is actually emitted during the test since the `console.log('emitted');` occurs
- the `exec` function is actually stubbed since the `console.log(cmd);` occurs

But the test fails with a timeout, with that error message:

```
~ % mocha --timeout 15000 -R spec event.test.js


  Event
    ◦ Event should be fired: ls -l
emitted
    1) Event should be fired


  0 passing (15 seconds)
  1 failing

  1) Event Event should be fired:
     Error: timeout of 15000ms exceeded
      at null.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/runnable.js:165:14)
      at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:110:15)
```

And if I remove the stub from my test, the test runs OK. And if i increase the timeout I still have the same problem.

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your stub changed the sync/async aspect of `process.exec()`.

The internal Node's implementation guarantees that the callback is always run in the next turn of an event loop:

```
myEvent = new Event(); // calls process.exec
myEvent.on('test', function() {
    expect(exec.cmd).to.equal('ls -l');
    done();
});
// process.exec callback will be called after all this code is executed
```

Your stub is calling the callback immediately:

```
myEvent = new Event(); // calls process.exec
// process.exec callback is called immediately
// test event is emitted before listeners are attached
myEvent.on('test', function() {
  expect(exec.cmd).to.equal('ls -l');
  done();
});
```

The solution is `process.nextTick()`:

```
var execStub = function() {
  var _self = this;
  return sinon.stub(proc, 'exec', function(cmd, callback) {
      _self.cmd = cmd;
      console.log(cmd);
      process.nextTick(callback);
  });
};
```

Your test has another problem: `_self` in the exec stub callback is referring to the global object, you are saving the value to `global.cmd`. You are expecting to have the value in `exec.cmd` in the test later.

Here is the final & fixed version of `execStub`:

```
var execStub = function() {
    var _self = sinon.stub(proc, 'exec', function(cmd, callback) {
        _self.cmd = cmd;
        console.log(cmd);
        process.nextTick(callback);
    });
    return _self;
};
```

See this [post](http://blog.izs.me/post/59142742143/designing-apis-for-asynchrony) for more information on callback asynchronicity.

Comment: Nice! Great educational answer! Thanks for taking the time to write it down!

Comment: + 1 for great answer. I have a similar problem but I couldn't implement your solution :( Could you take a look @Miroslav ? Thank you! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29133140/how-to-test-a-custom-module-running-node-fluent-ffmpeg-an-async-module